# How to place the popup based on the position of another div element using javascript and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to place a popup based on the position of leftnav element. basically place this popup next to the lefnav element such that it is vertically center to leftnav element.

below is the picture of how the popup should be placed

[image]

below is my code,

```
function LeftNav() {
    return (
        <Wrapper id="left_nav">
        </Wrapper>
    );
}

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 16px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
`;



function PopUp() {
    const left_nav_el = document.getElementById('left_nav');
    return (
        <PopupWrapper />
    );
}

const PopupWrapper = styled.div`
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
`;
```

i am not sure how to get the top-left corner of the leftnav and use it as coordinates to place the popup in center and 16px away to the leftnav.
could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: You can calculate the height of the left nav and divide that height by 4, Then that value will become the top starting point of your popup.

Comment: thanks could you provide it as an answer with some code.

Comment: I have a few questions: 1. is your popup height is fixed? 2. is your left nav will cover the full screen from top to bottom? So it would be better if you provide you HTML, CSS and JS code I will help you by editing the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
const App = () => {
function LeftNav() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
        height: "50px",
        background: "black",
        width: "50px"
         }}
    id="left_nav"
  />
);
}

 function PopUp() {
    return (
      <div
       style={{
         marginRight: "16px",
         height: "100px",
         background: "green",
         width: "50px"
        }}
       className="popup"
    />
   );
  }
  return (
    <div
      style={{ width: "100px", display: "flex", alignItems: "center"}}
        className="App"
      >
     <LeftNav />
     <PopUp />
     </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: In above code main component(App) wrap two child component LeftNav and PopUp and after that consume App component